# How to check my RAM configuration (Windows 7)?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

I would like to check my RAM configuration.

I know it is easy to check the total RAM installed on a computer (eg 32 GB), but is there an easy way to check in Windows if the RAM is e.g. 2x16 GB, 4x8 GB, 8x4 GB or 16x2 GB?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you don't mind using the command line, WMI can do this and is native with Windows XP and newer.

Simply run `wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag`

```
>wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Tag
BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator            Tag
BANK 0     2147483648  Bottom - Slot 1 (top)    Physical Memory 0
BANK 1     4294967296  Bottom - Slot 2 (under)  Physical Memory 1
```

(`DeviceLocator` will likely give you DIMM numbers on a desktop machine - the top/under slots are because I'm on a laptop. Both `BankLabel` and `DeviceLocator` formats may vary by machine.)

---

There is a lot more data available, but it doesn't display well in the limited columns of a command prompt. You can export it all to a text file for easier viewing (don't forget to turn off word wrap):

```
>wmic MEMORYCHIP get >data.txt
>start data.txt
```

And you can use those extra columns to customise the first command to give you, e.g., the manufacturer name, product number and serial number.

Comment: If you enter `wmic[return]` first, the command window is made scrollable horizontally and you can execute wmic commands interactively.

Comment: my BankLabel  start from BANK 2,where is BANK 0 and 1 ??? i have dell N5110 Loptop

Comment: @JesonPark As I said, those are very dependent on the specific motherboard, and *will* vary. Your motherboard manufacturer probably just reused a portion of the firmware and only physically placed slots corresponding to those identifiers.

Comment: Will this show empty slots too?

Comment: @TankorSmash No. This only shows installed memory, not the slots available (and the slots available according to mobo firmware might be different from physical slots on the board anyway).

Answer (score 26):

Yes, there a way to do this since [`CPU-Z`](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) can display that information. If if one program can do that then so can others.

---

[image]

<sup>Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with the CPUID website or the CPU-Z program.</sup>

Edit:

For linux: [`DMIdecode`](ftp://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/people/vitty/g630-v7.1-rc6/Info-dmi.txt)
For windows: [`wmic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392903%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MemoryChip` as already answered by Bob.

Comment: You're image is making me dizzy. It' answerception!

Comment: Thanks Hennes! Isn't this information accessible directly from Windows? Without installing any additional software?

Comment: @Vince: this software can run without installing

Answer (score 6):

You can use Powershell and get WMI Object, like the wmic command in CMD, except you can output it to a table using GridView.

Lots of information too, and no need to download/install any software!

```
Get-WmiObject CIM_PHYSICALMEMORY | Out-GridView
```

[image]

Cheers,

Devin

Answer (score 5):

Go to http://www.crucial.com, select the middle tab "system scanner" and run the plug-in. It will tell you the complete description of your memory configuration and the possible upgrades as well. It also give you other details related your motherboard, pc specific model, etc.

Comment: +1 for offering non-enthusiasts a way to get memory info (on a site dedicated to enthusiasts, no less)

Answer (score 0):

Use Belarc Advisor. It will show exact #of slots available and which are busy. And will show a capacity of each DIMM installed. However, It won't show you frequency or any other technical details about your memory.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Another route to the information is to use wbemtest. It is available in Windows in any system that has WMI and is a clunky way of viewing WMI data; it can be confusing to use but it can show everything and can do more with WMI than you likely need to. Execute it and then usually we can just click "Connect" and use the default (root\cimv2) to connect. Then click on "Enum Instances" then enter "Win32_PhysicalMemory". Then double-click on any of the result rows. Another relevant class name is "Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray".

An easier interface to WMI is [WMI Explorer](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2). In it click on "ROOT\CIMV2" in the namespaces then in the classes scroll down to the classes shown above.

Answer (score -3):

Open Task Manager > Click performance >

Click Memory. Here you will find total

installed ram and their bus speed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Please re-read the OPs question. He asked how to determine the capacity and count of the individual RAM modules installed, not the total installed memory.